# Maven: Omitting the goal from execution tag - How?

Tags: java, maven

I wonder if I can omit the `<goals><goal>actualGoal</goal></goals>` from the `<execution>` tag somehow. Since my plug-in project defines only one goal it seams to be obvious what to execute.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that since there can be multiple goals. [See this thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Writing-my-own-mojo-how-do-I-specify-a-default-goal-td5714539.html).

Comment: You can only omit the phase if your plugin defines a default life cycle binding but not the goal.

Comment: Ok thanks. If someone wants a green hook for an answer, just write one.